# Pivot pandas dataframe with dates and showing counts per date

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following  pandas DataFrame: (currently ~500 rows):

```
merged_verified = 

    Last Verified    Verified by
0   2016-07-11       John Doe 
1   2016-07-11       John Doe
2   2016-07-12       John Doe
3   2016-07-11       Mary Smith
4   2016-07-12       Mary Smith
```

I am attempting to `pivot_table()` it to receive the following:

```
Last Verified   2016-07-11   2016-07-12
Verified by
John Doe                 2            1
Mary Smith               1            1
```

Currently I'm running

`merged_verified = merged_verified.pivot_table(index=['Verified by'], values=['Last Verified'], aggfunc='count')`

which gives me close to what I need, but not exactly:

```
             Last Verified
Verified by
John Doe                 3
Mary Smith               2
```

I've tried a variety of things with the parameters, but none of it worked. The result above is the closest I've come to what I need. I read somewhere I would need to add an additional column that uses dummy values (1's) that I can then add but that seems counter-intuitive for a what I believe to be simple DataFrame layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add parameter `columns` and aggragate by `len`:

```
merged_verified = merged_verified.pivot_table(index=['Verified by'], 
                                              columns=['Last Verified'], 
                                              values=['Last Verified'], 
                                              aggfunc=len)
print (merged_verified)
Last         2016-07-11  2016-07-12
Verified by                        
Doe                   2           1
Smith                 1           1
```

Or you also omit `values`:

```
merged_verified = merged_verified.pivot_table(index=['Verified by'], 
                                              columns=['Last Verified'], 
                                              aggfunc=len)
print (merged_verified)
Last Verified  2016-07-11  2016-07-12
Verified by                          
John Doe                2           1
Mary Smith              1           1
```

Comment: Wow...`aggfunc=len` was it then. Thank you so much! This worked

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby`, `value_counts`, and `unstack`:

```
merged_verified.groupby('Last Verified')['Verified by'].value_counts().unstack(0)
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

**Example dataframe**

[image]

**Large dataframe 1 million rows**

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [
        pd.date_range('2016-03-01', periods=100),
        pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(letters, (10000, 10))).sum(1)
    ], names=['Last Verified', 'Verified by'])

merged_verified = idx.to_series().reset_index()[idx.names]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is a thorough answer, thank you! I will see if i can use groupby instead - the performance differences are significant!

Comment: Currently working through this - `groupby()` doesn't allow sub totals for rows and columns like `pivot_table()` does, correct?